# Endian issue with casting a packet to a struct

Tags: c, networking, packet, endianness

I'm using libtrace to parse network packets but am having, what I think is, an endian issue.

Here is the libtrace definition of a Radiotap packet:

```
typedef struct libtrace_radiotap_t {
    uint8_t     it_version; /**< Radiotap version */
    uint8_t     it_pad; /**< Padding for natural alignment */
    uint16_t    it_len; /**< Length in bytes of the entire Radiotap header */
    uint32_t    it_present; /**< Which Radiotap fields are present */
} PACKED libtrace_radiotap_t;
```

So I cast my `libtrace_packet_t` to this Radiotap struct and check the results:

```
link = (char *) trace_get_packet_buffer(packet, &linktype, NULL);

if (linktype != TRACE_TYPE_80211_RADIO)
    return;

rtap = (libtrace_radiotap_t *) link;

printf("%d %d %d %d\n", rtap->it_present, rtap->it_pad, rtap->it_len,
       rtap->it_present);
```

On my development machine, which is little endian, the Radiotap data from the packets in my pcap file is:

```
806959 0 72 806959
```

Which is correct. My development machine is successfully parsing the data I expect to see out of the pcap file.

When run on my production box, which is big endian, I see different values:

```
793775104 0 18432 793775104
```

Same packet within the same pcap file. Different Radiotap values. I suspect the issue is with the different endianness of the two machines. However, `rtap.it_version` is a `uint8_t` which, being single byte, shouldn't be affected by endian issues, no?

Comment: In both cases your 8-bit value `it_pad` is printing the same: `0`. You are printing `it_present` twice. You didn't print the `it_version`.

Comment: Well that was stupid of me. You've solved my Radiotap issue. Leads me to another issue, though. When casting my ``link`` to the [Frame Control struct](http://www.wand.net.nz/trac/libtrace/browser/trunk/libpacketdump/link_4.c#L31), my two machines show two different values for ``fc.type`` and ``fc.subtype``. Is this an endian issue with the ``uint8_t``'s in the FC struct?

Comment: POSIX has `htonl`, `ntohl` etc interfaces to convert between "network" and "host" endianess.

Answer (score 1):

That should be a endianness issue.
For 72, the hex is 0x48, and it's a uint16_t, so in the different endianness that's 0x4800 = 18432. That's right.
And for 806959 = 0xC502F, in the different endianness that's 0x2F50C000 = 793775104.

This may help:

```
#define T(x) (((x&0xff)<<24)|((x&0xff00)<<8)|((x&0xff0000)>>8)|((x&0xff000000)>>24))
```

Comment: So. If this is a 16-bit endian issue (and I concur that it is), whats with the 32-bit solution? The 16-bit version will be considerably less dense.

Comment: I would say it's a 16-bit issue and also a 32-bit for 0x2F50C000 = 793775104.

Comment: And I thought it's not difficult to adjust the code to fit a 16-bit issue. But I did mistake the problem, it's actually a `8-bit' issue(See comments below the question). XD

Answer (score 0):

The header structures returned by libtrace point to the header as it appeared on the "wire", i.e. without any attempt to convert to host byte order.

Radiotap header fields are always little-endian (as opposed to conventional network byte order, which is big-endian) so you'll need to compensate for that if you are going to try and parse the header manually. Just using `ntohl` won't work, as this expects the value you are converting to be big-endian.

A better approach, however, would be to use the built-in libtrace functions for accessing various radiotap fields, e.g. `trace_get_wireless_rate`, `trace_get_wireless_signal_strength_dbm` and many others. These functions will do the byte order conversion based on your host architecture, so you don't have to worry about it.

As for your problem with `struct ieee80211_frame_control`, this looks like a bug. I'd recommend [filing a bug ticket with the libtrace developers](http://wand.net.nz/trac/libtrace/newticket).