# C - Serialisation of struct into char* changes original data

Tags: c, serialization, struct

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651431/whats-the-best-practice-when-you-have-an-array-in-a-struct-in-c) question, I decided to serialise some data I need to send over a TCP/IP connection.

The data is pretty simple :

```
typedef struct whiteboard {
    int palladium, platine, zirconium, erbium, astate, californium;
} sharedData;
```

And my serialisation function is pretty simple as well :

```
void serializeWhiteboard (sharedData* message, char** packet) {
    int* r = (int*) packet;
    *r = (int)VALUE_FROM_ENUM; // just some enum to get the type of message sent
    r++;
    char* q = (char*) r;
    *q = '/'; q++; // delimitors for parsing
    *q = '/'; q++; // the message on the other end
    int* p = (int*) q;
    *p = message->palladium;    p++;
    *p = message->platine;      p++;
    *p = message->zirconium;    p++;
    *p = message->erbium;       p++;
    *p = message->astate;       p++;
    *p = message->californium;  p++;
    return;
}
```

In my calling program, I have the following code :

```
int main() {
    sharedData data = {0};
    // define the data values ...
    char* dest = malloc(sizeof(int) + 2*sizeof(char) + 6*sizeof(int));
    serialiseWhiteboard(&data, &dest);
    // And here, the first two fields of 'data' have changed
    // as if by magic, since I do not touch the fields in 
    // serializeWhiteboard() .
    return 0;
 }
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why the first two fields of data would change when I just read the values from it. And yet with some print values I was able to track it down to the second-to-last line in `serializeWhiteboard()`, just before the `return;`, which doesn't make any sense. The data is fine until right before the call to `return`.

Did anyone encounter such a problem before ?

Comment: There is zero need to pass `dest` by address to that function. It makes no sense at all. `dest` points to the buffer you want to serialize to. It should require no modifications. The address it holds should be passed by-value (single indirection) to a `char*` argument. and all of the `*p = ...` should be reworked to reflect said-same. You'll may also hit value-boundaries on your conversion from `int` to `*`, btw.

Comment: I'm C, 9 times out of 10, if you're casting a pointer, you're wrong. Maybe only 4 times out of 10 if you're casting to `(char *)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `char** packet` which is a pointer to a pointer to some chars.

You then treat that as `int *` which is a pointer to some ints.

You then overwrite the first `int` - so you're writing into 'dest' itself and not what it points to.  And since you write more after that, you're corrupting the stack.

Comment: Thanks, dumb mistake on my part. Too much modifications to the implementation of the function lead me to this error.

Comment: Why is packet a `char**`? Why not just pass a pointer to the space the packet should be assembled into?